# How to reload tableview when getting data from database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSString *country=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"namecountry"];
//url's
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someurl"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:country forKey:@"c_name"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];

NSString *response = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"%@",response);

res=[response componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"%@",[res objectAtIndex:18]);
show=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[res objectAtIndex:18]];
float f=[show floatValue];
show=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%",f];
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I've read posts and try lots of different ways but can't find the correct solution.So here is my problem: I have 3 tab bar items this one is the middle one.When i click it shows the tableview and it has detailTextLabel.text . I want to update the tableview when the user press the the tab bar i want him to see the updated one.

Now i try several ways as you can see [self.tableView reloadData]; i put it all the methods in the UITableView class can anybody tell me what is wrong i am doing in this?

Comment: Did you set the data (res) to the array your tableView uses as a datasource?

Comment: hmm i am sorry how can i set it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932288/iphone-dev-reload-data-of-a-table-view-from-a-child-controller-and-another-contr

Comment: in your .h file you have something like this: NSArray* myData

Comment: thanks ram for linking but i've already read that post still can't find the solution reloaddata isnt working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039011/how-to-load-data-in-tableview

Comment: well i create it yes i have that aray now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your .h file you have something like this: `NSArray* myData`

in the .m file the tableView gets data from this `myData` array
all you have to do is set the new data to the array your tableView uses as a datasource.

`self.myData = res;` right before you reload data